# MongoDB Read/Write problems with multiple inserts

Tags: mongodb, performance, insert

After 10 seconds of a multiple insert in mongodb (1.000 inserts aprox)
I have a problem with read/write performance.

The simple consecutive operations (during 10 seconds about) return timed out.

[Very high write operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkp8W.png)

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally we found the problem and we solved it.

The problem is that we use the TTL (time to live) to delete old entries. The inserts are very fast but when the expire has finished the deletes are too slow.

Regards.